# How to disabled a button on lightning datatable based on field value?

Tags: datatable, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I want to disabled a button on a lightning datatable based on a boolean field, I came to this solution:

```
const columns = [    
{ label: 'Client', type:'button',
        typeAttributes: {
            label: 'Client',
            disabled: {fieldName: 'Client__c' }
        } }
];
```

The problem is, I need to make visible when is true, but it actually doing the opposite, i search to a enabled property or trying something like this:

```
Client__c == true ? false : true;
```

but it doens't work..
I also try this solution [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/378384/conditionally-disable-button-in-lwc-datatable)

```
this.tableData = result.data.map((value) => ({ ...value, clientDisabled: ('Client__c' == true) ? false : true }));
```

And the column:

```
const columns = [    
{ label: 'Client', type:'button',
        typeAttributes: {
            label: 'Client',
            disabled: {fieldName: 'clientDisabled' }
        } }
];
```

Also, not work, all buttons became disabled.

Also, I would like to put a - when is disabled (and the field = false), like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'Client__c' == true` is always false; you're comparing two literal values that will never be equal. You'll want to use the data from the record instead:

```
this.tableData = result.data.map((record) => ({ ...record, clientDisabled: !record.Client__c }));
```

Comment: I was not able to get it working like that, the only way it works for me is doing it as described in "Creating Dynamic Row-Level Actions" here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation